# Upsampling in Python

Tags: python, resampling

I'm trying to perform upsampling in Python. Given the signal 's' and factor of upsampling N, I wrote the following code:

```
> y = np.zeros(N*len(s))
> for i in range(0, N*len(s), N):
>     for j in range(len(s)):
>             y[i] = s[j]
> return y
```

However, when I have a signal with first value '1' and factor of upsamling 3, my output of the function is like [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0] etc, no matter what the rest of the signal looks like. Is there a way to make this code work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to do this:

```
y = np.zeros(N*len(s))
for i in range(0, len(s)):
    y[i*N] = s[i]

return y
```

There are other ways in python that avoid explicit loops, for example:

```
y = [0] * (N * len(s))
y[::N] = s
```